# window.resize, How to wait for tab content is shown

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a few tabs and each tab has `tables` by `slickgrid` table library.

Each time moving to another tab. Layout of background tab is collapse.

If you go like this.

TabA->TabB->TabA(layout is collapsed)

I made function which fix the layout triggered by `resize`,but moving to another tab doesn't fire `resize`.

So I need to call windows `resize` by this `$(window).trigger('resize')` 
when I click tab.

```
<a class="nav-link active" id="headlineTab" data-toggle="tab" href="#head" onClick="$(window).trigger('resize');">head</a>
```

However it fires before all tab contents is shown, so table layout is not fixed. 
If you click tab twice. it fixes.

How can I wait for tab content is all shown??

(BTW, when I use slick carousel. background slide is not collapsed.
It's interesting);

Comment: What tab control are you using? They should raise events when tabs are changed or displayed. You should be able to hook to that to update the table

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I had with google maps initializing inside tab content.
This was couple years ago already so at that time we were using jquery UI tabs.
I think it's easier for you I show some snippets of logic and not a complete solution to your problem.

Checking the visibility of the active content 's parent:

- **when visible** use the dimensions of the parent OR use an aspect ratio in case of video, google maps, or other collapsed content
- **when invisible**, generically re-activate

Some snippets of logic:

```
activate: function () {
    if (google && this.map.length) {
        this.calculateMap();
        this.renderMap(this.coords);
    }
},

// google maps or your content inside a tab
cacheItems: function (cache, data) {
    this.map = this.container.find('.google-maps').eq(0);
    this.onParent = this.map.closest('.ui-tabs-panel'); // find the tab panel
},

calculateMap: function () {
    var self = this,
        parent = this.map.parent(),
        w, h, id, el;

    if (parent.is(':visible')) {
        w = parent.outerWidth(false);
        h = w * 9/16;
        this.map.css({ width: w, height: h });
    } else {
        id = this.onParent.prop('id');
        el = this.onParent.prevAll().find('a[href=#' + id + ']'); // find the tab trigger

        // generic single time event to re-activate
        el.one('click', function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.activate();
            }, 200);
        }.bind(this)); // rebind the scope
    }
},
```

Now you mentioned to trigger the resize event on your tabs. This is exactly what I'm doing here as well. Except, don't bind it onclick as this will persevere. Instead initialize your tabs on DOM ready.

Some logic of the tabs.js:

```
this.containers = $('.ui-tabs[data-class="tabs"]'); // added my own data-class here in HTML

activate: function () {
    var options = $.extend({}, {
        heightStyle: 'content'
    }, {
        activate: function () {
            $(window).trigger('resize');
        }
    });

    this.containers.tabs(options);
}
```

So I hope my logic is clear to you, so you can apply something similar in your code or what you've tried so far.